# How to edit a node's parent dynamically

Tags: javascript

anytime i try to edit a node parent dynamically I can't

for example I do :

```
myNode.json({data: {parent: 'New Parent', foo: 'bar'}})
```

it does not work, note that it will add the foo property but not the parent property. Same goes if I try to change the Id property.
How can I add / edit the parent property to a node ?

Answer (score 3):

```
      node.move({parent: 'new name'});
```